# Where is the code for mounting the ext4 filesystem in the linux kernel?

Tags: linux, debugging, kernel, breakpoints

I am just learning how to modify the linux kernel. I am using gdb in order to debug the kernel remotely but my breakpoints (b console_init, b start_kernel) doesn't work. now I want to try to set a breakpoint when the ext4 filesystem is mounting. Can anyone please tell me where in the code have I to set the breakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest running

```
grep -rn mount /usr/src/linux/fs/ext4/
```

or even

```
grep -rn 'mount.*(' /usr/src/linux/fs/ext4/
```

and going over the results? If you are going to work with the Ext4 code, you should get really familiar with it, anyway...